# Moving datasets from brightway2 to openLCA

Tags: brightway

So, from the brightway2 documentation I see that I can export datasets in Excel files, simaPro CSVs, ecospodld 1&2s, or JSONs (with the bw2 custom structure from what I understand).

openLCA allows imports form excel, simaPro CSV, JSON-LD among others.

So before I go though all combinations and potentially run into dead ends, I was wondering if there is a preferred (if any?) way to do that?

thanks!

Comment: Hey @myreich, where in the documentation did you find a export function for simapro CSV? I can’t find anything regarding this. Also the code doesn’t show anything like this. (I’m trying to export from brightway2 and import it to simapro).

Comment: hey @DanielStorch It has been a while and I never actually used bw2 in conjunction with SimaPro myself, but I think [this](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/IO%20-%20SimaPro%20export%20with%20ecoinvent.ipynb) would be the right point to start :) hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

OpenLCA uses a slightly different mental model than Brightway, so I am not sure what the best way to do this is (Brightway makes a strong assumption that there is a graph with fixed edges, while OpenLCA allows more flexibility). There certainly isn't one recommended way.

[Cauldron](https://www.cauldron.ch/) would be willing to fund a OpenLCA-compatible olca JSON schema exporter, but this doesn't help you right now...

You could also consider asking in the OpenLCA forums.